# Asus Computer Only Boots to BIOS

Tags: boot, bios, asus-laptop

over the past month I have been having some weird problems with my PC and today I think it just broke. While I was playing a game on my computer it just suddenly shut off for no reason. When I turned it back on it just took me to the BIOS screen. I thought that this was temporary and just exited, but when I did it took me back to BIOS and now I cannot get out. The random shut offs have been happening for some time, but I have never been taken to the BIOS screen afterward. Plus it only shuts off randomly on battery power and it only happens about once a day usually. I am stuck with no knowledge about anything on BIOS and hope that I can get back to my PC. Thanks.

SPECS:
Asus X75A
Aptio Setup Utility Version 2.15.1226

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like it can't find a boot medium. Within your BIOS there should be an option to specify what to boot from. Is your hard drive listed within?

Possibilities are:

- Failed/Corrupted hard drive
- Some odd attempt to boot from a boot medium that isn't the hard drive, and it never attempts to (Remove any USB devices as a matter of course)
- Motherboard fault preventing it from finding the devices to boot from.

As it rebooted whilst using it, my assumption would be it displayed a blue screen and then couldn't access the hard drive again for whatever reason, hence why you're thrown back to the BIOS.